# How can I check if two values are not equal to null with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var store = window.localStorage;
var a = store.getItem('AccountID');
var b = store.getItem('CityID')
```

How can I make it so my refreshGrid("Page"); function only runs if both of these are set to values?

Comment: check for (a===null) && (b===null)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check that they are explicity `null`, just compare the values to `null`:

```
if(a !== null && b !== null) {
    //Neither is null
}
```

If you are storing values in there that should always evaluate to `true`, you can skip the equality checks (if nothing is stored in that particular storage item this will still fail, since `null` is falsy):

```
if(a && b) {
    //Neither is falsy
}
```

Comment: @AlphaMale - I'm not sure what you mean. Both statements will evaluate to `true` if `a` and `b` are not null (in the first case) and not falsy (in the second case).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var a; var b;

if (a == null && b == null) {
   //a and b are null
}
```

OR

```
if (!a && !b) {
   //a and b are null, undefined, 0 or false
}
```

For James: **alert(null == undefined) // returns true**

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first one doesn't check that "a and b are null", it just checks that they evaluate to false. They could be `null`, `undefined`, `0` or `false` to name but a few.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [guard condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29) at the top of your function:

```
function myFunction() {
    if(a==null || b==null) return;
    // ... rest of the code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code is what your looking for.

```
if(!!a && !!b){

  alert("this is not null")

}else{

  alert("this is null")

}
```